# Swapping two Integers using Bitwise Operator

Tags: logic, bitwise-operators, swap

How can we swap the values of two integers using bitwise operator so that no additional temp varialble should be declared?

Comment: Thanks ! I got the answer but its hard to find out the solution searching how to swap,as i didn't know XOR is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using 16-bit integers here. If the neither of the integers is greater than 0x00FF or uses only its LSB, then you could do this:

```
a = 0x002E;
b = 0x007A;
//first transfer b into a's upper byte
a |= b << 8;
//transfer a's lower byte into b
b = a & 0x00FF //b is now equal to a's original value
//finally right shift a's upper byte
a >>= 8 //a is now equal to b's original value
```

I dont think you can swap the values of two 16-bit integers, greater than 0x00FF, as they are, without using a third variable since when you shift bits, you lose them unless you save them someplace. You will have to cast one of those integers to *long*, which would give you 32 bits to work with, and then perform nearly the same operations as above.